# Send an email using Azure SendGrid in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, sendgrid

I am following [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-sendgrid-nodejs-how-to-send-email#reference-the-sendgrid-nodejs-module) in order to send an email using SendGrid:

```
var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')("username", "passowrd");

var email = new sendgrid.Email({
    to: 'user@company.com',
    from: 'user@company.com',
    subject: 'test mail',
    text: 'This is a sample email message.',
    html: 'This is a sample <b>HTML<b> email message.'
});

sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json){
    if(err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(json);
});
```

But I am getting the error:

> sendgrid.Email is not a constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using sendgrid in various projects, I have been using the documentation from https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs.
I wonder if Azure's documentation is still up to date...

Any way if you use the `@sendgrid/mail` package and configure your account properly. This code should work:

```
const createSampleMessage = {
  to: 'user@company.com',
  from: 'user@company.com',
  subject: 'test mail',
  text: 'This is a sample email message.',
  html: 'This is a sample <b>HTML<b> email message.'
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") {
  await sgMail.send(createSampleMessage);
}
```